# Issues with Building intent - in Android Developer tutorial

Tags: android

I'm trying to follow the android developer tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity?authuser=2#java) and I'm getting an issue I don't know how to resolve. I'm trying to do the Build Intent step and it does not seem to recognize the `editText` part of `findViewById(R.id.editText)` and when running the app i get the error message:

```
error: cannot find symbol
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable editText
location: class id
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the whole MainActivity.Java document so far:

```js
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /** Called when the user touches the button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Show your .xml file code

Comment: dear, show us your xml. i think your issue there

Answer (score 0):

Check your xml layout file for the `EditText` variable,
it should have the same `Id` as in the Java class, for example:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:text="@string/text" />
```